# $n$-th roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does the $n$-th roots of unity form a ring? I think the collection is only closed under multiplication. Is there any another composition under which the collection is closed? If it is ring then when it is UFD, ED, PID?

Comment: For $n$ even and at least $2$ the two roots $\pm 1$ of $x^n=1$ show that set is not closed under addition.

Comment: Is there  any another composition ? Diffrent from addition and multiplication under which collection  is closed

Comment: @guronkar If you make up any sort of composition then the $n$th roots of unity are no different from any other finite set of size $n$ (and of course there are rings with exactly $n$ elements).  The composition should preserve *something* in order for the question to have much meaning.

Comment: It's a nice and creative question.  But the answer is simply, no, unfortunately.  It just isn't and not really rectifiable.